# Subgroups of finite index of a certain subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Let $G$ be the subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})=\bigg\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{Z}^{2\times 2} \ \Big| \ ad-bc=1  \bigg\} $ defined by
$$ G=\bigg\{\pm\begin{pmatrix} 1 & h \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \ \Big| \ h\in\mathbb{Z}  \bigg\} $$
I want to show that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ of index $h<\infty$, then there are three possibilities, namely

- $H=\Big\langle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & h \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\Big\rangle$; or
- $H=\Big\langle \begin{pmatrix} -1 & h \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\Big\rangle$; or
- $H=\Big\langle \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\Big\rangle
      \Big\langle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & h \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\Big\rangle$.

To prove this we write $H=H_{1}\cup H_{2}$, where $H_{1}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & h \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\in H \right\}$ and $H_{2}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} -1 & h \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\in H \right\}$. We also write $f:=\min\left\{h>0:\begin{pmatrix} 1 & h \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\in H\right\}$.
Then, it is easy to show, using the euclidean algorithm, that $H_{1}=\Big\langle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & f \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\Big\rangle$. Hence, if $H_{2}=\emptyset$ we are in the first type. If $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\in H_{2}$ then we can show that we are in the third type of subgroup. Indeed, we already have that $H_{1}=\Big\langle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & f \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\Big\rangle$ and so consider a matrix $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & h \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\Big\rangle\in H_{2}$. Then,

$$ \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & h \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & h \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\in H_{1} $$

and so $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1 & h \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & f \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{n}$, for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence,

$$ \begin{pmatrix} -1 & h \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & f \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{n}\in \Big\langle \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\Big\rangle
    \Big\langle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & h \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\Big\rangle $$

If $\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\not\in H$ then I should be in the second type of subgroup, but I do not know how to prove it. Also I have not yet use the assumption that $H$ is of finite index. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have used the assumption that $H$ is of finite index already, because there is a chance that the set in the 'min' used for defining $f$ is empty, but if this were the case, $H$ would either be trivial or equal to $\left\langle\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right\rangle$. Also maybe show an ismorphism from $G$ to $\{\pm 1\}\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ so your notation becomes more compact. Then the question would be equivilant to proving that $H=\langle(1,h)\rangle,\langle(-1,h)\rangle$ or $\langle(-1,0)\rangle\langle(1,h)\rangle$. I hope this helps.

Comment: You are right. That' s where I used the finite index assumption. Though, this does not help me, as it is just a rephrase of the problem!